# PHP memory in a heavy load environment

Tags: php, memory-management

My question, Silly as it is, is as follows :

If I have a PHP script that occupies 1MB of RAM, Does the RAM usage scale with traffic?
To be exact, if N denotes the number of visitors, Is my projected memory usage 1MB * N?

I assume it must work like that, But how does a website with thousands of visitors a day handle memory?

Comment: depends on your infrastructure, php-fpm or fastcgi is diffrent from apache/mod_php

Comment: and also depends how many resources you are using on the script

Comment: Depends on how many __concurrent__ requests the server(s) is getting

Comment: if a single request takes up 1 MB and is processed in a second, then 1000 users requesting the same page at the same time will require only a gigabyte of RAM. Most servers have well over 8 GB available, so in that simplified example you could easily scale to 8000 visitors per second. If you need more, put in more RAM or buy a new machine and load balance the requests. That's of course simplified and not taking your exact infrastructure into account, but it should give you an idea.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, 
so basically under heavy load it is possible to run out of ram if you're not load balancing your server.

I'll research more on the whole php-fpm, fastcgi and mod_php as to be honest I'm not knowledgeable at all in that area. 

Thanks alot :)

Comment: Gordon speaks theoretical.. in real live you will be limited by the number of process apache/nginx is allowed to spawn (see apache `MaxClients` directive. With this setting you can limit to the spec of your server. -- Apache (prefork/mod_php) needs more ram for the same amount of clients than for example nginx/php-fpm.